# Why does Python return an empty string when I slice with a negative step?

Tags: python-3.x, string, slice, reverse

```
a = "Today is Valentine's Day"
a [1:10:-1]
```

Return is ''

Why does this code return an empty string instead of returning the string slice backwards?

Comment: Do you want: `a[10:1:-1]`?

Comment: @chumi, The starting value should be higher to slice backwards. As @costaparas, mentioned, it should be like `a[10:1:-1]` to make it work.

Comment: Yes exactly, think of it like a loop: if you are incrementing, then you have to start at a lower number/index. If you are decrementing, you have to start at a higher number/index.

Comment: Thanks a lot @costaparas. This worked.

Comment: @SumitSChawla. Thank you. Got it.